# Avoiding MatchError when matching over subset of possible values

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was wondering if it's possible to match over a subset of the possible values without having a `MatchError` thrown.

```
def foo(bar: String): Int = bar match {
    case "x" => 0
    case "y" => 1
    case _ => -1
}
```

In the above example, I understand that you absolutely have to match over all possible values, as the method has to return something.

```
def foo(bar: String): Unit = {
    bar match {
        case "x" => isX()
        case "y" => isY()
    }
}
```

However in the above example, I don't feel that it would be necessary to match all possible values, since the method doesn't depend on the result of the match, since it is only calling methods. If `bar` was some value other than "x" or "y" then a `MatchError` would be thrown, which is extremely annoying and avoiding this would require adding a pointless `case _ =>` clause.

It would be so much more convenient and concise if you didn't have to match over all possible values if you just wanted to *do* something, rather than *return* something. Is this possible?

Comment: Scala is a functional language, so technically you *always* return something, `Unit` has a value `()` and that's what you return. You suggest different syntax for different return types?

Comment: @VictorMoroz Good point. That could be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is a partial function where a failure to match does nothing. That's pretty much the definition of `collect` except we don't have a collection. That's easily fixed, resulting in

```
def foo(bar: String): Unit = {
  Some(bar) collect {
      case "x" => isX()
      case "y" => isY()
  }
}
```

which does what you want.

Comment: How is it better than `case _ =>` ?

Comment: I think that use of `case _ =>` is more explicit and less work.

Comment: It's not necessarily "better", It does, however, address the OP's question and show it is possible.